# New to jquery: simple jquery slideshow plugin, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Trying to integrate a simple jquery slideshow plugin, but I'm having some issues. In the docs it talks about installing 'grunt' and installing 'node dependancies'. I do not understand this. I am new to jquery and trying to use this plugin and learn more about jquery in the process.

I created a jsfiddle to try and see the functionality using the 'example' setup in the slideshow's documentation: https://github.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider

Can someone help let me know where I am going wrong? The jquery aspect is not functioning and the css also see to be incorrect (the red circle is placed in the wrong position).

Thank you, any help will be very much appreciated as I try to learn more about jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/deCPM/1/

HTML

```
<title>Tiny Circleslider: A lightweight cross browser circular carousel.</title>
    <div id="rotatescroll">
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/hdr3.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/hdr2.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/hdr1.jpg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#rotatescroll { height:300px; position:relative; width:300px; }
#rotatescroll .viewport{ height:300px; position: relative; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; width:300px }
#rotatescroll .overview { position: absolute; width: 798px; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;  left: 0; top: 0; }
#rotatescroll .overview li { height:300px; width:300px; float: left; position: relative; }
#rotatescroll .overlay {background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/bg-rotatescroll.png) no-repeat 0 0; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height:300px; width:300px; }
#rotatescroll .thumb { background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/bg-thumb.png) no-repeat 50% 50%; position: absolute; top: -3px; cursor: pointer; left: 137px; width: 100px; z-index: 200;  height: 100px; }
#rotatescroll .dot { background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/bg-dot.png) no-repeat 0 0; display: none; height: 12px; width: 12px; position: absolute; left: 155px; top: 3px; z-index: 100; }
#rotatescroll .dot span { display: none; }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#rotatescroll').tinycircleslider({ interval: true, dotsSnap: true });
        });
```

jquery.tinycircleslider.js   (https://github.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/blob/master/lib/jquery.tinycircleslider.js)

Comment: You just had to Include  The plugin in ur Fiddle ,HTML  :)

Comment: I see that now, thank you. Hehe silly mistake but it will help me not do it again. But I am confused why the 'interval' is not working and the pictures do not change?? http://jsfiddle.net/yx9vF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my verification the problem is, the jquery.tinycircleslider.js script is not added to your project, check the

```
alert("test")
```

is not working. [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wtzsg/)

And the working fiddle is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx9vF/)

Comment: ahh okay, thank you very much. But why do you think the interval is not working and the pictures do not change? I even tried adding the 'intervalTime' from the initialize options, but the pictures do not change. http://jsfiddle.net/3uZUb/